# Intrinsic Asymmetry(?) of Spherical Coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates, curvilinear-coordinates

Today during my classical mechanics class, I got into a discussion with my professor about a certain asymmetry of spherical coordinates. Expressing the square magnitude of velocity in a spherical coordinate system yields
$$
\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \left( \dot\theta^2 + \dot\phi^2 \sin^2{\theta} \right),
$$
where $\theta$ denotes the angle from the $z$ axis and $\phi$ from the $x$ axis.

My question is why there is an explicit $\theta$ dependence in the expression, considering the choice of coordinates is spherically symmetric. (More accurately, my question is why the Lagrangian for a point mass in a central field has an explicit dependence on $\theta$. My instinct was that $\theta$ should be a cyclic coordinate due to spherical symmetry.)

We agreed that such dependence arose from the essence of spherical coordinates, specifically the different natures of the $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinates. And we have enumerated some other consequences of this:

- $\theta$-translation is not a well-defined rotation in a specific sense. While $\phi$-translation is always a rotation about the $z$ axis, there is not a single axis about which all rotations occur due to $\theta$-translation.
- $\theta$-translation is not one-to-one. A point on the positive $z$ axis is mapped to many different points while having no point associated to it, and vice versa for the negative $z$ axis.
- While a consistent transformation can be given such that only the $\phi$ coordinate of a point is translated (rotation about the $z$ axis), the same cannot be said for $\theta$.

What we could not conclude on was how to formally state why such things happen. We have dismissed the explanation that quantifying $\theta$ requires a certain $z$ axis, as we also need to specify an $x$ axis to quantify the $\phi$ coordinate. I tried to look for concepts like some (a)symmetries of a curvilinear coordinate, but to no avail. Is there a concept related to the phenomena I described? Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at what happens in$4$ and higher dimensions? I think one then sees how all the angles play  different roles - you seem to want them to be in some sense equivalent, but that's not how they enter into the equations.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Will definitely look into higher dimensions! It's not that I want them to be equivalent per se, but I wanted to understand from a fundamental level what makes them different.